# Create a settings page

Tags: visual-studio, settings

I'm making an ASP.Net MVC 3 application in VS 2010. I have a task to create a settings page which would make the columns from the tables in my database with specific permissions (read, read/write etc.).

It's the first time I have a task of this kind and I have no idea on how to make this.

I tried going right click on the project in VS and then go to Settings. There was a link which says that my project didn't have a settings page, so I clicked it to create one. There appeared a table with settings but there are just public/internal access modifiers. I can't seem to find write/read.

Is this the right way of creating a settings page? Or is there another?

Comment: What you created has *nothing* to do with a "settings page" in a website. It's for application settings storage and setting the default values of those application settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry Andrew. I answered your question in quite a rush previously. So, I think my answer became quite unclear. I'm so sorry. I will try my best to answer this more clearly. My answer can be quite long and I hope you are patient enough to finish reading this. :-)
Actually, your problem can be solved in very easy way. Believe me! You actually don't need a Setting page for this.
I suppose you will have a `Users` table in your database, for storing user accounts for your system. Right! And again, I suppose that `Users` table will have at least these following fields.

- UserID   [ This must be the primary key for the table. Right! ]

  UserName

  Password

  Email   [ This is kind of optional. ]

I only suppose your database has this kind of schema. Or else, there must be other ways to set the permissions for your users in the table.

Alright, create another table called `Permissions` in your database. That `Permissions` table will handle the permission rights for your users in the above `Users` table. Ok! Then, you have two tables. One is your original `Users` table and another is `Permissions` table.

Ok! Our new `Permissions` table will have at least following fields:

- ID   [ This is the primary key for this table. ]

  UserID   [ This will come as foreign key from your previous Users table. ]

  PermissionRead   [ this field will hold `boolean` data type, or `bit` data type. `True` or `False` for `Boolean` and `0` or `1` for `bit`. This is entirely depends on the type of DBMS you use. ]

  PermissionWrite   [ again, same as `PermissionRead`. ]

Alright, now you have two tables. These Permission read and write fields are for holding the permission rights for your users.
If you have the exact db schema as I described above, then you will have the following kind of relationship like this:
**Users** table
*UserID* | *UserName* | *PW*
U-001 | Tim | timpassword
U-002 | Jim | jimpassword

**Permissions** table
*ID* | *UserID* | *PermissionRead* | *PermissionWrite*
1 | U-001 | True | False
2 | U-002 | True | True 

So, you can see that, User Tim which is UserID U-001 has Read-only permission and User Jim who is U-002 has both read-write permissions.
So, you can check the condition of these fields when a particular user login to the system. If he or she has `PermissionRead` value `True` and `PermissionWrite` value `false`, then that user has read-only permission right. Or else, if both values are true then that user has read-write permission. Ok! 
I tried my best to explain this, and I really do hope you can understand my answer. I really do...!!!
My suggestion is that, you should try this method first. And, if you are alright with this, I can explain more how to set group level permissions from this method. Ok! 'Cause my answer became quite long, and I fear you become bored reading this... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a setting page for tasks like this. Easiest way to give permissions to the users in ASP.Net is that, you need to create a table in your database. Let's just call it **Permissions**. 
Then create these fields in that table:

- PermissionID (datatype something you want)

  UserID (this must be the foreign key from your Users table)

  Read (boolean or bit type)

  Write (the same as Read)

  Both (the same as Read)

You have a table which is linked to your user table. You can set permissions for the users in the Users table in this Permission table, by setting these boolean (true or false), or bit (0 or 1).
Then, when your user login to the system, you can check these "read", "write" and "both" values from that Permission table, and allow that particular user based on these true or false values. 
For instance, if a particular has only Read value true and the other values false, then you can tell that, that user has "read-only" permission.
That's the basic idea for creating user permissions with databases. O'course, you can do some advanced features from database tools. But, I think this is the simplest way to do so. 
 And you can add many permission types you want in that table.
You can even create groups with this method. Like, giving permissions to a particular group will give permission all users belong to that group.
**Wish you good luck...!!!**

Comment: Your opening sentence is not supported by the rest of your post. Exactly *how* would those permissions be set, if not by some Page or administrative interface on the website? Your proposed table structure and permissions structure are also quite questionable - three separate fields for `Read`, `Write`, and `Both`? Wouldn't it be better to simply set both `Read` and `Write`? And your answer ignores that it also requires a `Permissions` table, which describes the permissions being assigned. Finally, your answer does not really offer any suggestions for creating Groups or how to use them.